# Using template meta programming (TMP) to make homogeneously storable templated configurants

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming

Sorry for the atrocious title.

The scenario is that I have a configuration system in my program, that needs to able to hold values of all types. These values (configurants) need to be held in a homogenous container.

For example: (this is pseudo-code, I'm not sure how this would actually look)

```
configurant i(64);
configurant b(true);
configurant f(128.f);
configurant custom(Color(255, 255, 255));

vector<configurant> confs;
confs.emplace_back(i);
confs.emplace_back(b);
confs.emplace_back(f);
confs.emplace_back(custom);

// some form of accessing the vector with proper configurant type here:
// casting?
```

Like I said, I don't know how this system would look in practice. I know that a statement like

```
auto color = confs.at(3).rgb();
```

is generally not possible in C++, but is there something I could do with templated metaprogramming to try and get as close as possible to this solution?
(perhaps the configurants could be mapped with their type? but this would not be a compile time operation)

I'm looking to create a system that is storable homogeneously, immediately accessible (not stored on the heap) and that evaluates the validity of operations at compile time.

Open to any suggestions.

**And before the comments come in, I've experimented with `std::any/std::any_cast`, `std::variant`, the visitor pattern, and other things of that nature. I'm not looking to use any of those systems.**

***EDIT*** To avoid confusion, there are N configurants: it is not a statically sized group of configurants. More configurants would be added by the user of this interface.

***EDIT 2*** Additional example of desired usage

```
class foo {
configurant enabled;
configurant bar;
public:
    foo() {
        this->enabled = configurant(true);
        this->bar = configurant(5);
    }

    void body() {
        if(this->enabled) {
            std::cout << (this->bar < 100) << "\n";
        }
    }

    // It also needs to be kept in mind that these configurant classes
    // cannot be templated (directly, at least), since they need to be stored in 
    // a homogeneous container.
};
```

Comment: Do `confs` has to be a `vector` of `configurant`. Or could it be `tuple<int,bool,float,Color>`?

Comment: Well this interface is meant to be able to accept ANY and all types. So the tuple wouldn't work. int, bool, float, and Color were just four examples I decided to use. There are N configurants, not a static number of them. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: So any data type could be stored at *any* index of a storage with any number of elements but the compiler has to check that the operations performed at any of these indices are consistent with the data stored? (Ah! OK I think I get it: we are on the first of April today! This was a good one, thank you ;^)

Comment: @prog-fh Yes, that is essentially what I'm after. When you put it like that, it's beginning to sound more and more unlikely that this is possible.

Comment: as suggested by @generic_opto_guy, the nearest solution relies on ``std::tuple`` but the number, order and types of the stored data has to be chosen at compile time.

Comment: @prog-fh Perhaps I could write a preprocessor macro to place this data into a tuple? Also, not that I'm set on using TMP or anything, but I've seen it mentioned that similar system have worked using TMP. Any ideas on that? 

Haha, this is not an April Fools joke, by the way.

Comment: @marcyeo or `auto foo = std::make_tuple(64, true, 128.f, Color(255, 255, 255));`, or C++17 `std::tuple foo { 64, true, 128.f, Color(255, 255, 255) };`

Comment: @Caleth it's of N elements of any types

Answer (score 1):

Because of this requirement
*"that evaluates the validity of operations at compile time."*,
this means that your example
`auto color = confs.at(3).rgb();`
will only work with the *index* `3` known at compile time
(why not `2` or `4`?).
This *index* is not very relevant/useful in this situation.

May be should you simply consider a structure providing
the required data with a proper name instead of a
*compile-time index*?

```
struct Confs
{
  configurant<int> i;
  configurant<bool> b;
  configurant<float> f;
  configurant<Color> custom;
};

...
Confs confs{64, true, 128.f, Color(255, 255, 255)};
auto color = confs.custom.rgb();
```

Something like this could rely on a *compile-time index*
but I don't really see the benefit over a named member.

```
auto confs=std::make_tuple(64, true, 128.0f, Color{255, 255, 255});
auto color = std::get<3>(confs).rgb();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. The interface should be able to accept any and all types. There are also N number of configurants, meaning a statically sized structure would not work in this case. 

In regards, to your first statement (why not index `2` or `4`), I wrote it like that because accessing an `.rgb()` member for, say, a "bool" or "int" value would (should) be undefined behaviour. (Also, there is no index `4`)

Comment: @marcyeo so the sentence *"that evaluates the validity of operations at compile time."* is misleading. Sorry I don't understand the requirement.

Comment: For example, if I were to do `auto test = confs.at(1);` Then try to evaluate it in `if(test) {}`, that should work. If I were to do `auto test_2 = confs.at(3);`, and `if(test_2) {}` that shouldn't work because the `Color` class is not evaluable in that way, while a `bool` is. Using C++, being statically typed, I know this exact behaviour is not possible.

Comment: I'll include an additional example of my desired usage in the main post.